# Wrap a Uint8List with RandomAccessFile

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some code that can read large files via `RandomAccessFile`, however on the web when you open a file you don't get a `RandomAccessFile`, only a `Uint8List`. Is there a built in way that I can wrap a `RandomAccessFile` in a `Uint8List`?

Comment: How do you use `RandomAccessFile` and how do you get `Uint8List`?